# Does Discretization improve Classifier Performance?

Tags: classification, random-forest, binning

I am trying to understand the basics of how and when is it ok discretize a variable.

Below are some papers that support Supervised Discretization:

[Improving Classification Performance with Discretization on Biomedical Datasets](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2656082/#:%7E:text=The%20use%20of%20discretization%20in,to%20further%20improve%20classification%20performance.)

[Feature selection via discretization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/617056)

On the other hand, there is

[Visual Revelations](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/09332480.2006.10722771?needAccess=true)

[Frank Harrel's page on problems caused by discretization](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous)

and a lot of other posts that discourage binning

[What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable)

[Is binning of continuous data always bad for statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421911/is-binning-of-continuous-data-always-bad-for-statistical-tests?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Therefore, if I take the target class into account to decide the bins, it would help in feature selection in classification, but not arbitrary binning of continuous values ?

There is also an argument that says tree models do implicit binning, and that by pre-binning, we are not giving complete information to the model.

[Does binning of ranges make sense for a Random Forest?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330670/does-binning-of-ranges-make-sense-for-a-random-forest)

Appreciate any clarification.

Comment: See: (almost a dup?)  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230750/when-should-we-discretize-bin-continuous-independent-variables-features-and-when